# Most efficient code to set a sort order column / assign a sequential series of numbers to a column?

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got a table that will hold a sequence of rows I want to be able to change the order in which I query and display them. So I've created a column called "sortorder" that is an integer.  I'm looking for a quick SQL statement re-order these column values any time I make an adjustment (i.e. bump a column up, down, to top or bottom).

So, given a table like:

```
table xxx:
data varchar(x)
sortorder int(10)
..
```

When I want to parse rows I'll do something like this:

```
select * from xxx order by sortorder desc;
```

Would I propose doing is, setting the value of sortorder to be sequential in increments of 2, such as the first row sortorder=2, the second sortorder=4, etc.

Then if I arbitrarily want to move any row back one, I simply set sortorder=sortorder-1.

Then I run a routine to re-assign all the values of sortorder in increments of 2 (order by sortorder ASC) and reset all the numbers with the new row in its proper place.

I figure when I initially add a row to the table I will set the sortorder= max number of existing rows *2 + 2;    What would be the best way to do this in SQL?

I'm looking for the most efficient statement to re-order the values of sortorder as such.

I'm also open to ideas on other ways you might maintain user-changeable sort order for an table of rows...

Thanks!

Comment: Appropriate index will perform better than this. Please show `SHOW CREATE TABLE table` and `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table` than I'll try to propose you exact solution.

Comment: Maybe I didn't get you right - are you trying to shuffle the rows ? Move one up/down ?

Comment: I'm thinking, I'm looking for a few specific statements:

1.  A SQL UPDATE statement that will parse the table and re-assign the value of sortorder in increments of 2 (order by sortorder ASC)

so let's say I have a table like this:

`rownumber,sortorder

1,2

2,4

3,6

4,5

5,9`


in the above example, I have bumped row 4 so that it will end up being row 3.  To bump the row up, I make sortorder=sortorder-3 (I misspoke earlier when I said -1)

Now I want to re-number the sortorder columns and reset them to be again in increments of 2.

Comment: ok but what's the factor on which you want to re-assign the values ?

Comment: Here's a statement that does it via SELECT:

` SELECT (@rownum:=@rownum+1)*2 'soval',p.*  FROM xxx p,(select @rownum:=0) r WHERE p.something=47 ORDER BY sortorder ASC
`

Comment: in a nutshell i want a single update statement that will cycle through the rows ordered by sortorder ascending, and re-number the value of sortorder as 2,4,6,8, etc.

Comment: for example, given this table with column sortorder values: 2,4,6,5,9  it would re-order them as 2,4,5,6,9 then change the values to 2,4,6,8,10  (in effect turning the column with sortorder=6 to 8 and sortorder=9 to 10

Comment: What I'm asking about is how you calculate `sortorder` values on the very begging. Anyway if you're trying to make a list than would be much better to use common list elements - like `id` and `pointer_to_next_element`. So every row will just contain information which one is next to it. In that you don't need to step by 2 to make a room and reorder more if you need more room.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, you don't need to number things in steps of 2 in order to bump a row up/down. Just use a step of 1, and then swap a number with the one preceding/following it, and wrap that all in a transaction.

Comment: @halfer in that case it'll have to swap for every one step on the stack. For ex. to move row from 100 to 1 it'll need to swap 99 times. And yes, transactions are the must here.

Comment: @pawel7318: I wouldn't bother with 99 swaps - for a bump top/bottom, just swap with `MIN(sortorder)` or `MAX(sortorder)`. As you say, a transaction is good - here in particular it deals with a rare but possible race condition.

Comment: @halfer: maybe I did wrong example. Try with 870->354 where MIN=1 and MAX=1000

Comment: interesting ideas.. i have not worked with transactions... I do not expect there to be a huge number of rows (probably less than a few hundred max)...   I like the idea of having a button that can move a row up 1, up 5, to top or bottom, and with my way I just reset the sortorder appropriately and make sure it's an odd number so it doesn't collide with any other rows, then reset all the values again.

To answer the other question, whenever adding a row I would set sortorder to equal max(*) rows *2 + 2, so the first row would be sortorder=2.

Comment: Read about `linked list`. You can find some details on [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list). There are usually great explanations on many `ANSI C` tutorials as it's the common thing there. You need to make no more than 2 updates to move one row anywhere you want with it and don't need to recalculate anything.

Comment: @pawel7318: from the question, isn't the problem just top/bottom/up-one/down-one? That said, you _could_ have a button that pushes a row up 400 odd rows, if you wanted one `:)`.

Comment: Normally I'd want to make something as efficient as possible but this particular set of statements would only be run administratively, so it's not subject to heavy optimization...

So, I know how to populate the table (just set sortorder= max rows*2+2 whenever I add a row)... and to bump a row up, I do update table set sortorder=sortorder-3; to bump a row to top, update table set sortorder=1.   All I really need is a UPDATE statement that re-assigns the sortorder values in increments of 2 starting with 2 that I can call after any change to the value creating an odd-numbered sortorder

Comment: @pawel7318: perhaps I have misunderstood the problem, but a linked list doesn't seem appropriate here. If each row points to the primary key of the next, and primary keys are of arbitrary value, how can an `ORDER` statement be used to read the rows in the right order? You'd have to start editing primary keys, which doesn't sound good!

Comment: Noep, you don't need to. You just need to `UPDATE` this `pointer` field and select them with `ORDER BY pointer`. You never touch their original primary keys.

Comment: @S.ov: I still am not quite sure why you want to reassign _all_ sort order values. My suggestion earlier was just to edit two at a time, and I think that's all is required (unless, as I say, I have misunderstood the problem).

Comment: I apologize if I didn't make the issue clear..   all I really need is an UPDATE statement that steps through the table on the order of sortorder ASC, and re-assigns the sortorder column according to the following formula: rownum*2+1

Comment: @halger: to make a room for the next change.

Comment: can we move to the chat ?

Comment: yes, if I'm bumping a row up 1, it might be more efficient to simply swap two sortorder values, but I may want to bump something to the top, bottom or somewhere else.. if I bump a row up 10, then I have to update 11 rows.. it seems a lot easier to just use a single re-order statement for every instance - I know this is not super efficient but it's very simple and straightforward and would only be called rarely.

Comment: I'm going to make another question since it seems, the way I worded this has confused people.

Comment: @halfer: please accept my apologies

Comment: @pawel, no worries, not a problem - and now you know the tab trick, it'll be harder to make a typo `:)`. (Voting to close, as this question has now been duplicated twice).

Comment: possible duplicate of [UPDATE statement to re-assign a column value according to a numeric formula](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23329898/update-statement-to-re-assign-a-column-value-according-to-a-numeric-formula)