# UPDATE statement to re-assign a column value according to a numeric formula

Tags: mysql, sql

Given a table that would have values like this:

```
name, sortval, dept

bob,   2,       1
tom,   4,       1
mary,  6,       1
sam,   8,       1
tim,  10,       1
```

The sortvalue determines the order in which I output the list so a

```
select name from table order by sortval ASC
```

would look like this:

```
bob
tom
mary
sam
tim
```

Now let's say I want sam to be moved up 2 rows after bob.   I execute this statement:

```
UPDATE table set sortval=sortval-5 where name='sam'
```

now the table looks like this:

```
name, sortval, dept

bob,   2,       1
tom,   4,       1
mary,  6,       1
sam,   3,       1
tim,  10,       1
```

Here comes the question....

I want the simplest statement to re-order the sortval values so they are once again, all even numbers starting with 2 going up incrementally by 2, in the order of sortval so it would end up like this:

```
name, sortval, dept

bob,   2,       1
sam,   4,       1
tom,   6,       1
mary,  8,       1
tim,  10,       1
```

I figure there is a simple way to have some sort of compound UPDATE that can reset the sortval values as above.

I'm simply looking for a very specific UPDATE statement that can re-assign the value of sortval according to a simple formula of rownum*2 in the order of sortval, and wanting to know if messing with sortval in a statement using ORDER BY sortval would cause any problem?

Answer (score 0):

A `CASE` statement may help. In this example:

- the `source`, sam, is at position 8
- the `target`, bob, is at position 2

Replacing the variables with the actual values, the following statement shifts everything down 2 from the source, leaves the between members as is, sets the target equal to source, moves the rest down:

```
postgres=> SELECT * FROM test order by sortval;
 name | sortval
------+---------
 bob  |       2
 tom  |       4
 mary |       6
 sam  |       8
 tim  |      10
(5 rows)


postgres=>      UPDATE test
postgres->        SET sortval = CASE WHEN sortval <= 2 THEN sortval - 2
postgres->                           WHEN sortval = 8  THEN 2
postgres->                           WHEN sortval >= 8 THEN sortval - 2
postgres->                           ELSE sortval
postgres->                           END;
UPDATE 5
postgres=> SELECT * FROM test order by sortval;
 name | sortval
------+---------
 bob  |       0
 sam  |       2
 tom  |       4
 mary |       6
 tim  |       8
(5 rows)
```

That would move something up the list. Similar logic could be applied for moving down a list. And it assumes negative numbers are fine an that just the relative ordering is of interest.

Comment: I need something that will work for any number of rows with different sortval values.. it need to traverse the rows and re-assign the value