# UPDATE statement to re-assign a numeric value based on a formula

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Given a table that has the following columns: (the x column is used to demonstrate what rows are changing)

```
x,myval
a, 2
b, 3
b, 5
d, 8
e, 9
f, 10
...
```

I want the most efficient way to run a mass UPDATE on the table and change the value of the `myval` column based on this formula:

```
myval = (row#)*2 in ORDER myval ASC
```

So that after this UPDATE operation, the table would look like this

```
x,myval
a, 2
b, 4
b, 6
d, 8
e, 10
f, 12
...
```

I figure there is a way using some sort of compound UPDATE/SELECT statement and a variable that is derived.  Here's a way to show the value via SELECT:

```
SELECT (@rownum:=@rownum+1)*2 'newval',p.*
FROM table p,(select @rownum:=0) r
WHERE xxx
ORDER BY myval ASC

newval, x,myval
2, a, 2
4, b, 3
6, b, 5
8, d, 8
10, e, 9
12, f, 10
```

So can someone show me the appropriate UPDATE statement that would do this in a single swoop, or some other ways?

UPDATE... column x is an arbitrary column - it could contain any data.  I was including it so you can see which rows are being altered.

Comment: I know you were going to re-ask [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23328795/472495), as you felt the conversation had not understood your problem, but you appear to have done so twice. Thus, this question seems to be a [duplicate of this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23329898/472495). So you know, the social cost of duplicating a question is creating extra work for volunteers who could be more usefully helping someone who has asked their question once. Thus, please dup only sparingly, and if you must, hyperlink to past identical/similar questions.

Comment: In fact, I'd say it most cases it is better to edit a question than to create a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 Update thisTable set myVal = 
    2 * (Select Count(*)
         From Table
         Where x <= thisTable.x)
```

Comment: hmmm.... x is an arbitrary column - it could contain anything, so you can't use it as a reference that way.

lol.. clever approach though

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way is probably to use an `update`/`join`:

```
update table p join
       (SELECT (@rownum := @rownum + 2 as rn, p.*
        FROM table p cross join
              (select @rownum : =0) const
        WHERE xxx
        ORDER BY myval ASC
       ) toupdate
       on p.x = toupdate.x
    set p.myval = toupdate.rn;
```

Based on your comment to the other answer, though, I'm not 100% sure that the join condition is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I ended up doing this in PHP.

Assuming x represents a unique/primary key column in the table:

```
$q="select x from `table` order by myval ASC";
$count=0;
$r=mysql_query($q) or die ("Error during: ".$q. " " .mysql_error());
while ($rec=mysql_fetch_array($r)) {
  $count++;
  $sortval=$count*2;
  $q2="update `table` set myval='$sortval' where x='".$rec['x']."' LIMIT 1";
  $r2=mysql_query($q2) or die ("Error during: ".$q2. " " .mysql_error());
}
```

It seems a nested loop in PHP works just as well.  I was curious if this could be done in a more simple SQL statement, but in the end I coded it in PHP and MySQL.